# Centos 6.7 Yum Nothing to do error

Tags: linux, centos, yum

My dedicated server is running on Centos 6.7
Yum does not seem to be working at all. Whichever package I try to install with Yum, does not work at all following No package "xyx" available and nothing to do error.

How do reset the whole yum to default.

I tried with

```
yum update
```

and

```
yum clean all
```

nothing works.

Example: when I try to install a package.

```
root@ns321982 [~]# sudo yum install -y tigervnc-server
Setting up Install Process
No package tigervnc-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
root@ns321982 [~]# subscription-manager list
-bash: subscription-manager: command not found
root@ns321982 [~]# yum search tigervnc-server
No Matches found
```

Example: When I try to update yum

```
root@ns321982 [~]# yum update
Setting up Update Process
base                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                            | 4.3 MB     00:00
epel/metalink                                                              |  25 kB     00:00
epel                                                                       | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                            | 5.0 MB     00:00
extras                                                                     | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                          |  30 kB     00:00
updates                                                                    | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                         | 4.3 MB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bind.i686 32:9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: bind = 32:9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 for package: 32:bind-chroot-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1.i686
---> Package bind.i686 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.7 will be an update
---> Package bind-devel.i686 32:9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 will be updated
---> Package bind-devel.i686 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.7 will be an update
---> Package bind-libs.i686 32:9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 will be updated
---> Package bind-libs.i686 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.7 will be an update
---> Package bind-utils.i686 32:9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 will be updated
---> Package bind-utils.i686 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.7 will be an update
---> Package initscripts.i686 0:9.03.46-1.el6.centos.1 will be updated
---> Package initscripts.i686 0:9.03.49-1.el6.centos.4 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: sysvinit-tools >= 2.87-6 for package: initscripts-9.03.49-1.el6.centos.4.i686
--> Processing Dependency: module-init-tools >= 3.9-25 for package: initscripts-9.03.49-1.el6.centos.4.i686
---> Package libcgroup.i686 0:0.40.rc1-15.el6_6 will be updated
---> Package libcgroup.i686 0:0.40.rc1-17.el6_7 will be an update
---> Package ntpdate.i686 0:4.2.6p5-2.el6.centos will be updated
---> Package ntpdate.i686 0:4.2.6p5-5.el6.centos.4 will be an update
---> Package openssh.i686 0:5.3p1-104.el6_6.1 will be updated
---> Package openssh.i686 0:5.3p1-114.el6_7 will be an update
---> Package openssh-clients.i686 0:5.3p1-104.el6_6.1 will be updated
---> Package openssh-clients.i686 0:5.3p1-114.el6_7 will be an update
---> Package openssh-server.i686 0:5.3p1-104.el6_6.1 will be updated
---> Package openssh-server.i686 0:5.3p1-114.el6_7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 32:bind-chroot-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1.i686 (@updates)
           Requires: bind = 32:9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1
           Removing: 32:bind-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1.i686 (@updates)
               bind = 32:9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1
           Updated By: 32:bind-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.7.i686 (base)
               bind = 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.7
           Available: 32:bind-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.1.i686 (base)
               bind = 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.1
           Available: 32:bind-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.2.i686 (base)
               bind = 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.2
           Available: 32:bind-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.4.i686 (base)
               bind = 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.4
           Available: 32:bind-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.5.i686 (base)
               bind = 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.5
           Available: 32:bind-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.6.i686 (base)
               bind = 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.6
Error: Package: initscripts-9.03.49-1.el6.centos.4.i686 (base)
           Requires: module-init-tools >= 3.9-25
           Installed: module-init-tools-3.9-24.el6.i686 (@base)
               module-init-tools = 3.9-24.el6
Error: Package: initscripts-9.03.49-1.el6.centos.4.i686 (base)
           Requires: sysvinit-tools >= 2.87-6
           Installed: sysvinit-tools-2.87-5.dsf.el6.i686 (@base)
               sysvinit-tools = 2.87-5.dsf.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Return when I type

```
root@ns321982 [~]# yum repolist
repo id                   repo name                                                      status
base                      CentOS-6 - Base                                                1,068+103
epel                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386                   9,199+710
extras                    CentOS-6 - Extras                                                     40
updates                   CentOS-6 - Updates                                             1,068+103
repolist: 11,375
```

I basically want to install desktop environment like GNOME so that I can control dedicated hosting server remotely using GUI.

Answer (score 0):

There are same packages with different versions on different repositories. Run `yum info bind-chroot` to find out which repositories provide `bind-chroot` package (You should do that for `initscripts` package.

After finding repositories that provide same packages, keep the most update/stable one and disable the other/others.

I think `extras`  repository may cause the problem. You can disable it and retry to run `yum update`

Answer (score 0):

Another case is when the package is excluded. For example my system's yum.conf file contains exclude=*.i386 *.i586 *.i686

This means any i686 package is excluded by default! A workaround for that case is:

sudo yum install --disableexcludes=all foobar.i686.rpm
yum cleanall
yum update